# ESLint does not output all files with errors and warnings to the terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, eslint, eslintrc

When I start the `npx eslint .` command from root directory of my project it doesn't output all files which has eslint errors and warnings (only some), but in files that are not output to the terminal, errors and warnings are highlighted. So why is this happening and how to make ESLint run through all project scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Did it. The `npx eslint .` command looks in .js files by default, and the files I needed to check were in .jsx format. So the answer is: `npx eslint. --ext.js --ext.jsx`.